# Badge placement in list where width:49%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a tab as the image shown below.
[image]

The problem here is that the badge for the bell is not on the right place and I can't figure this out.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
    <li class="active" id="received_fs_li" style="width: 49%;">
        <a  id="received_fs_link" class="text-center" href="#" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li id="sent_fs_li" style="width: 49%;">
        <a id="sent_fs_link" class="text-center" href="#" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <span class="badge" id="badge-new-friendship">1</span>
                                                                
    </li>
</ul>
```

The css which concerns the code is this one :

```
.navbar-right .badge {
    background-color: #1ab394;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

But to me the problem comes from the `width: 49%;` because if I remove it the badge looks good but it doesn't look pretty because the list does not take the full width...
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all badges are used as `<span/>` inside another element, for example:

```
<a href="#">Inbox <span class="badge">42</span></a>
```

The snippet below is from your code with the above correction:

```css
.badge {
  background-color: #1ab394;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active" id="received_fs_li" style="width: 49%;">
    <a id="received_fs_link" class="text-center" href="#" data-toggle="tab">
      First tab
      <i class="fa fa-lg fa-arrow-up pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="sent_fs_li" style="width: 49%;">
    <a id="sent_fs_link" class="text-center" href="#" data-toggle="tab">
      Second tab
      <i class="fa fa-lg fa-bell pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span class="badge" id="badge-new-friendship">2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I don't want to have text, just the centered bell icon with the badge :/